# Searching Data via Map reduce programing

Tags: oracle, search, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When i import my data from oracle(suppose 1TB) into my HDFS via SQOOP,how is the data going to be stored in the file.
Oracle has structured data,how will the data be in HDFS?like will it be denormalized,and just like a simple text file or what.?
Its like mapper converts it in key value pairs.Now suppose I have search criteria of finding people whose age is greater than 20,how are we going to write a Map reduce program for that.?

Answer (score 0):

In hadoop there is no concept of table relation ship.If you have data in normalized form then sqoop individual tables into hdfs and put all these into one folder say for example "raw".
Then check for the tables you need to query and then join them by using "hive or pig" then let these tables be in another folder in hdfs say "denormed".
then build hive tables upon those data and then query them.

the HDFS can store data as is when you are sqooping it ,but you can cahange the format by specifying it during sqooping or building hive tables,generally text is not preferred rather convert it to binary formats like "avro","parquet" etc.
For more reference check this link
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-3-2/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_26_8.html
Thanks